# How to extract values from a numeric-keyed nested JSON field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-json

I have a MySQL table with a JSON column called `sent`. The entries in the column have information like below:

```
{
 "data": {
  "12":"1920293"
 }
}
```

I'm trying to use the mysql query:

```
select sent->"$.data.12" from mytable
```

but I get an exception:

```
Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 9.
```

Any idea How I can extract the information? The query works fine for non-numeric subfields.

Comment: Try `"$.data.\"12\""`.

Comment: Try using the function `JSON_CONTAINS`.

Comment: @wchiquito it doesn't work. it consider string `' "12" ' ` as key

Comment: This seems to be bug in mysql engine as I'm getting  `Error: UNKNOWN_CODE_PLEASE_REPORT:` here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bLUtMxWwAH9A2hT7LEaATS/0

Comment: @wchiquito it worked like so too. Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

@Ibrahim,
You have an error in your code. If you use number (or spaced words) as key in a JSON data type in MySQL, you'll need to double-quote it.

Therefore, the correct MySQL statement in your case is:

```
select sent->'$.data."12"' FROM mytable;
```

Thanks,
@JeffreyKilelo